# Xamarin.Forms : How to get and add swipe events on Android and ios?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

・I use Xamarin.Forms

・on UWP, it worked

・But on Android and ios, I don't know how implement it.

This is my code

```
/* Depends on the platform */
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform) {
            case Device.iOS:
                /* iOS */
                // ????
                break;
            case Device.Android:
                /* Android */
                // ????
                break;
           
            case Device.UWP:
                /* UWP */
                /* SwipeGestureRecognize */
                var leftSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Left };
                leftSwipeGesture.Swiped += async (sender, e) => {
                    // dosomething;
                };
                var rightSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Right };
                rightSwipeGesture.Swiped += async (sender, e) => {
                     // dosomething;
                };
                Layout.GestureRecognizers.Add(leftSwipeGesture);
                Layout.GestureRecognizers.Add(rightSwipeGesture);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

/* Add * /

Outputed Error

```
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
[ame.calenderap] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 10027(810KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 89% free, 2866KB/26MB, paused 25us total 7.627ms
[Mono] GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 497 objects 504 opaque 5 colors 497 colors-bridged 497 colors-visible 497 xref 3 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.04ms tarjan 0.09ms scc-setup 0.06ms gather-xref 0.00ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.05ms
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 9.34ms
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 4.69ms, stw 5.53ms promoted 1600K major size: 2464K in use: 1803K los size: 1024K in use: 162K
**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Add

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer'.'
```

Please support me!

Thanks!

Comment: GestureRecognizers are cross platform, you should not need to create them per-platform

Comment: Thank u for ur advice.
Could it be due to the use of scroll view?
I use a ScrollView as a parent of RerativeLayout.

Comment: I got an Error
"System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: which line throws the exception?  Which element is null?

Comment: This
"[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)')."

Comment: you need to look at the exception object to get the stack trace, or add some exception handing your code to identity the root cause

Comment: Sorry, please teach me how to get the stack trace??

Comment: there are thousands of existing posts and articles about using VS debugging tools

Comment: Ok thank you Jason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swipe Gesture Recognizer is cross platforms and you can read the document about how to [Add a swipe gesture recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe).

Here is an example:

In xaml:

```
<BoxView Color="Teal" ...>
    <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
        <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Swiped="OnSwiped"/>
    </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
</BoxView>
```

In code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var boxView = new BoxView { Color = Color.Teal };
    var leftSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Left };
    leftSwipeGesture.Swiped += OnSwiped;
    boxView.GestureRecognizers.Add(leftSwipeGesture);
}

private void OnSwiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: I programmed like it, but it doesn't work on scrollview...

Comment: Can you share us your codes in scrollview?

Comment: OK, looks like you get solution there.

Comment: Maybe so! Thanks :)

Comment: If my answer helps you, you can upvote and accept:).